# Case insensitive regex in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: node.js, regex, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to do case insensitive search using $regex in hyperledger fabric chaincode written in node. My query looks like this:

```
    const title = RegExp('Simple Title', 'i')

    const query = { selector: {  
          docType: DocType.someType, 
          title: { $regex: title }} 
     }
```

I also many other queries like using erlang syntax:

```
    const title = 'Simple Title'

    const query = { selector: {
          docType: DocType.someType, 
          title: { $regex: `(?i)${title}` }} 
        }
```

...or providing options prop:

```
    const title = 'Simple Title'

    const query = { selector: {
          docType: DocType.someType, 
          title: { $regex: title, $options: 'i' }} 
        }
```

However, nothing seems to be working. It either return all records or an error. Is it me doing something wrong or fabric does not support such queries?

I know fabric documentation recommends not using regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more testing and realized that this problem only occurs in tests that are using *'@theledger/fabric-mock-stub'* npm package. Even though tests fail, deployed chaincode works as expected. I assume that it's not the problem with the hyperledger, but some kind of bug in the *'@theledger/fabric-mock-stub'* package.

Answer (score -2):

From the [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#find-expressions), you can see that the `$regex` operator supports:

> A regular expression pattern to match against the document field. Only matches when the field is a string value and matches the supplied regular expression. The matching algorithms are based on the Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) library. For more information about what is implemented, see the see the [Erlang Regular Expression](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html)

From the [Erlang Regular Expression](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) link, we see:

> `caseless`
>   Letters in the pattern match both uppercase and lowercase letters. It is equivalent to Perl option /i and can be changed within a pattern by a (?i) option setting. Uppercase and lowercase letters are defined as in the ISO 8859-1 character set.

So in summary, the caseless version of `Simple Title` would be `(?i)Simple Title`.

If you do this and get an error, please update your question with the exact query you're trying, and the exact error returned.